# How do I Integrate Cortana with my Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, cortana

I'm updating a Windows Phone app I wrote a while back, just bug fixes and a few new features. I thought I might add a bit of Cortana in there, just cos I can.

I found **[this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/Integrating-Cortana-with-your-App)** example and **[this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx)** which both look pretty straightforward, only it doesn't seem to work I get no errors and have traced the code and no exceptions are being thrown. It just doesn't seem to do anything.

I have followed the example to the letter, even tried a separate (new WP8) app and still no joy. Its a windows Phone 8 app using Visual Studio 2012.

I run the app as it says. But no new commands are shown when I say "what can I say" and when I speak my commands it just goes to the search page even though it has the exact phrase that I spoke and is in my voice command definition file.

Anyone got any ideas ? Or examples that actually work ?

Comment: Thats a perfectly fair question. Why the down vote ? You can be sure I fully researched pretty much all the examples and questions on here with no joy hence my asking the question

Comment: Do you just want to launch the app using Cortana or add some more custom commands? 
Also would suggest you to rather go with UWP for Windows10.

Comment: I want to launch an app but. I found the problem. It seems that although UK phone have Cortana on them, you can't integrate with is unless you have a US phone. I verified this by changing my phone to US and the integration works. Back to UK settings and it doesn't work. The app will remain Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 until Windows Phone 10 is wider established, that said I have no planned changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your Voice Commands get installed. You need to add voice Commands for each region separate Judging by your comment you only have en-US commands but your phone is set for en-gb. If that is the case here is how your Commands should look:

```
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1">
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-US">
[Your Commands here]
</CommandSet>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.1">
<CommandSet xml:lang="en-GB">
[Your Commands here]
</CommandSet>
```

You can also add en-IN with no extra work (Copy and Past), to address add Cortana for India. In general when your Commands don't show up in Cortana's what can I say section it is do to the VCD file not getting installed /updated.

Comment: Why did I not think of that, staring me right in the face. Thanks loads